NativeWind will transform className into style as an array, can it be one single style object
i use both NativeWind and twrnc in my project.
suppose i have a component looks like this.
import tw from "twrnc";
...
const Test=(props)=>
{
  console.log(props);
  return <View style={tw.style(`border`,props.style)}>
    <Text>hello</Text>
  </View>
}

and when i try to use this component like this
<Test className="bg-red-400 text-red-400" />

it will print out the props like this:
style: [{backgroundColor: '#f87171'},{color: '#f87171'}]
the NativeWind transformed classname into style but as an array.
then tw.style will popup an error which says TypeError: str.trim is not a function (it is undefined) 
is it possible to ask NativeWind not transform classname into style array, but a single style object?
for example,  style: {backgroundColor: '#f87171', color: '#f87171'}

what i've done is write a mergeStyle function like this
import { style } from "twrnc";
export const mergeStyle = (...args: any[]) => {
    let _args = Array.from(args).reduceRight((res, arg) => {
        if (Array.isArray(arg)) {
            res.push(...arg);
        }
        else {
            res.push(arg);
        }
        return res
    }, []);
    return style(..._args)
}

then use it in Test component like this
const Test = (props) => {
  return (
    <View style={mergeStyle(`border`, props.style)}>
      <Text>hello</Text>
    </View>
  );
};

